# Make a program delete a file which it just created

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way for me to stop an action in python so that another action in the same python script can start? Or is there a way to split a program into two parts so that they can run after the first part has ended?

```py
import os

t = 'Testfile input...'

f = open('File.txt', 'w')
f.write('{}'.format(t))

os.remove('File.txt')
print('File has been removed')
```

This is what I always get.

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is 
being used by another process: 'File.txt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the file before you can remove it with `f.close()`

```
import os

t = 'Testfile input...'

f = open('File.txt', 'w')
f.write('{}'.format(t))
f.close()
os.remove('File.txt')
print('File has been removed')
```

Otherwise your file system will not allow you to delete it because it still in use.